# How can I format common lisp code (including newlines) from the command line?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, code-formatting

I'm looking for a way to pretty print/beautify/autoformat Common Lisp source code from the command line. I basically want a clone of the functionality of `black` for python (see https://github.com/psf/black). It would be a command line tool with minimal dependencies (I don't want to have to run it from within emacs, for example) that is idempotent and automatically inserts and removes newlines where appropriate, as well as doing the indenting.

Basically I'd like to be able to feed it source code consisting of just a single line and have it produce a readable file. Does anything satisfying all or even some of these requirements exist? I've already looked at most of the low-hanging fruit on github, and they only seem to do auto-indentation, not autoformatting (can't break up long lines). If not, is there any sort of precedent for this sort of thing in lisp, or is it unreasonably difficult for some reason that's specific to this language?

Comment: Part of the solution is built into the language, see [the Lisp Pretty Printer](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_b.htm).  However, you still have a problem in that the source code would need to be `read` in, and any reader macros would be expanded immediately and not preserved.

Comment: For the general case you need to know the system context for the source code at hand, because you'd need to know any custom reader macros that should be in effect.  For example, `[` and `]` are often used for DSLs, but in the standard readtable, `apple][` is a valid and unremarkable symbol.

Comment: @Svante I'm a bit of a newbie, what is meant by "system context"? How constrained does the problem have to be in order for this to be a non issue?

Comment: Basically: no macros (outside of those in the standard), no reader macros.  Then it's trivial.  But those are severe constraints.

Comment: Did you see the 3 projects listed here? https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#linting-code-formatting trivial-formatter, cl-indentify, lisp-format (it looks like trivial-formatter wants an ASDF system to format and not a single file). cl-indentify didn't split-up a long line in my test. Didn't try the other two.

Comment: mmh lisp-format is an elisp batch script and it didn't succeed in splitting a big line with my test. Remains trivial-formatter…

Comment: Yes, sadly I've tried all of them, and none of them split up a big line. :(

Answer (score 7):

[This should be a comment but it's way too long.]

This is somewhere between hard and impossible.  Consider the following form, here given on one long line:

```
(with-collectors (odd even) (iterate next ((i 0)) (when (< i 100) (if (evenp i) (even i) (odd i)) (next (1+ i)))))
```

How should this be indented?  Well, here's how a fully-lisp-aware editor might indent it:

```
(with-collectors (odd even)
                 (iterate next ((i 0))
                          (when (< i 100) 
                            (if (evenp i)
                                (even i)
                              (odd i))
                            (next (1+ i)))))
```

and that's ... magnificently wrong.  Here's how that same editor will indent it a little later on:

```
(with-collectors (odd even)
  (iterate next ((i 0))
    (when (< i 100) 
      (if (evenp i)
          (even i)
        (odd i))
      (next (1+ i)))))
```

This time it's got it right.

What changed?  Well, what changed was the language: in particular the language in the second example has been extended to include a `with-collectors` form which the editor now knows how to process and also an `iterate` form which it also understands.

So this might seem like an obscure point, but it's not.  Because Lisp's *whole point* (arguably) is that in order to solve problems you progressively and seamlessly extend the language from the base language you start with to the language you want to use to solve the problem.

This means that many Lisp programs consist of a series of extensions to the language, followed by a program in this new, extended language, in which the problem is solved.  Lisp is a *language-oriented programming-language*.

What *that* means is that the only really reliable way of knowing how to indent a Lisp program is to *ask the program*.  In the example above, initially the system thought that `with-collectors` was a function and it indented it like that.  Later on, when it knew the definition, it realised that it was a `let`-style construct and indented it properly.  Similarly for `iterate`.

What all this means is that a standalone tool really has no hope of indenting a substantial Lisp program well, because to do that it needs to know more about the program than it can without *being* the program.  This, of course, is why Lisp encourages 'resident' development environments, where the program being developed is loaded into the development environment, rather than 'separated' ones where the development environment is more-or-less completely separated from the program being developed.  It's possible that a standalone tool could get most of the way there by parsing the definitions in the program and spotting the ones which are extending the language.  But to do that right, again, requires you to be the program.

Being a language-oriented programming language comes with significant benefits, but also with costs, of which this is unfortunately one.

---

If your task is very restricted and if you really want to take some big expression which is all on one line (and so, probably, has no comments) then something which will attempt to do this is below.  You'd need to wrap this up into a program.

**CAVEAT EMPTOR.  This code is *certainly* unsafe and can execute arbitrary code depending on its input.  Do *not* use it unless you are certain that the input you are feeding it is safe.  So, don't use it, in fact.**

```
;;;; Note horrid code, This is *certainly* unsafe
;;;
;;; This uses EVAL which I think is necessary here, but is what makes
;;; it unsafe.
;;;

(in-package :cl-user)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (warn "UNSAFE CODE, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK."))

(defvar *tlf-handlers* (make-hash-table))

(defmacro define-tlf-handler (name ds-arglist &body forms)
  (let ((formn (make-symbol "FORM")))
    `(progn
       (setf (gethash ',name *tlf-handlers*)
             (lambda (,formn)
               (destructuring-bind ,ds-arglist (rest ,formn)
                 ,@forms)))
       ',name)))

(define-tlf-handler in-package (package)
  (let ((p (find-package package)))
    (if p
        (progn
          (format *debug-io* "~&Setting package ~S~%" package)
          (setf *package* p))
      (warn "no package ~S" package))))

(define-tlf-handler defpackage (package &body clauses)
  (format *debug-io* "~&Defining package ~S~%" package)
  (eval `(defpackage ,package ,@clauses)))

(define-tlf-handler defmacro (name arglist &body forms)
  (format *debug-io* "~&Defining macro ~S~%" name)
  (eval `(defmacro ,name ,arglist ,@forms)))

(define-tlf-handler eval-when (times &body forms)
  (declare (ignore times forms))
  (warn "Failing to handle eval-when"))

(define-condition pps-reader-error (reader-error simple-error)
  ())

(defparameter *pps-readtable* (copy-readtable nil))

(set-dispatch-macro-character
 #\# #\+
 (lambda (s c n)
   (declare (ignore c n))
   (error 'pps-reader-error
          :stream s
          :format-control "Can't handle #+"))
  *pps-readtable*)

(set-dispatch-macro-character
 #\# #\-
 (lambda (s c n)
   (declare (ignore c n))
   (error 'pps-reader-error
          :stream s
          :format-control "Can't handle #-"))
  *pps-readtable*)

(defun pp-stream (s &optional (to *standard-output*))
  (with-standard-io-syntax              ;note binds *package*
    (let ((*readtable* *pps-readtable*)
          (*read-eval* nil)
          (*print-case* :downcase))
      (do ((form (read s nil s) (read s nil s)))
          ((eq form s) (values))
        (format to "~&")
        (pprint form to)
        (when (and (consp form) (symbolp (car form)))
          (let ((handler (gethash (car form) *tlf-handlers*)))
            (when handler (funcall handler form))))))))

(defun pp-file (f &optional (to *standard-output*))
  (with-open-file (in f)
    (pp-stream in to)))
```

Comment: Do you know of anything extant that comes somewhat close to this functionality? Maybe a command line tool that does what you suggested a fully-list-aware editor might do?

Comment: well explained!

Comment: @bxw: No, I don't.  But I'd never use such a thing, so that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  They may not though, because people who write Lisp generally will have no use for such a thing I expect.

Comment: @ignisvolens Maybe I asked the wrong question, then. What do people who write Lisp do? They simply have the style guide memorized, or they exclusively use an editor with a plugin that manages this sort of thing for them?

Comment: This is an entirely different question than your "formatting 1 giant line" first explained use case! Yes, there is not much syntax or code style to watch, on the contrary of Python, so the editor does it right for you. If you still want to ensure uniformity, we have some tools, like the ones I described in my other comment.

Comment: @bxw: I think the answer is they use smart editors, yes.

Comment: The built-in Vim editing mode for Lisp, as well as the 3rd-party Vlime plugin, both have hard-coded lists of symbols that introduce special indenting rules. Rather than trying to semantically infer the correct indenting, it just looks at the head of the form being analyzed, and indents according to any special rules that are defined for that symbol. So if you use the CFFI library, you would have a list of hard-coded symbols like `with-foreign-string` etc. that need to be indented like `let` forms. A standalone tool could ship with a big list of such symbols, and let the user add their own.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using emacs as a Command Line Tool would be the best solution ...

The thing is, if you would use emacs with the correct settings, indenting is done for you by emacs.

True, emacs is not easy to use for a beginner. Very overwhelming. It took me several attempts with long periods of giving up inbetween.

I listed in [a blogpost](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b?sk=b178a230dc2ba72c2a5af7ea86857fc0) a set of minimal commands I use when writing lisp code. A list, which I would have loved someone gave me when starting emacs.

And I also wrote [a blogpost](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b?sk=b178a230dc2ba72c2a5af7ea86857fc0) for setting up a Common Lisp environment using Roswell the best Common Lisp implementations manager and package manager I have seen so far.

Emacs, you can then run in the terminal/command line - by starting it with `$ emacs -nw` which is the short for `--no-window-system`.
Then it runs - like vim - inside the terminal and you have to use your keys only to move your cursor around within it and edit the code. - However you can still open new "windows" and buffers inside the terminal (vertically dissect your window by: `C-x 3` and horizontally by `C-x 2`. Jump cursor from one window to the other: `C-x o`.

Such commands I listed all in a cheat-sheet manner in the firstly mentioned [blogpost](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b?sk=b178a230dc2ba72c2a5af7ea86857fc0).

Whenever you install emacs there is a `.emacs.d` file in your home folder (at least in Linux and MacOs - in Windows I am very inexperienced, since I don't use it since more than 10 years ...). And inside that is an `init.el` file which controls the start behavior of emacs and where you configure the settings.

As kind of a minimal working `init.el` for Common Lisp programming - **when using Roswell** (means if you followed all installation instructions in my [second blogpost](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b?sk=b178a230dc2ba72c2a5af7ea86857fc0), you can copy paste there (the language for the settings in this init.el file is emacs-lisp):

```
;; initialize/activate package management
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq package-archives '())

;; connect with melpa emacs lisp package repository
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa"     . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

;; initialization of package list
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)

;; Ensure `use-package` is installed - install if not                                                                                        
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                       
;; slime for common-lisp                                                                                               
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                       



;; to connect emacs with roswell
(load (expand-file-name "~/.roswell/helper.el"))

;; for connecting slime with current roswell Common Lisp implementation
(setq inferior-lisp-program "ros -Q run");; for slime;; and for fancier look I personally add:
(setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy));; ensure correct indentation e.g. of `loop` form
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-cl-indent);; don't use tabs
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil);; set memory of sbcl to your machine's RAM size for sbcl and clisp
;; (but for others - I didn't used them yet)
(defun linux-system-ram-size ()
  (string-to-number (shell-command-to-string 
                     "free --mega | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}'")))(setq slime-lisp-implementations 
   `(("sbcl" ("sbcl" "--dynamic-space-size"
                     ,(number-to-string (linux-system-ram-size))))
     ("clisp" ("clisp" "-m"
                       ,(number-to-string (linux-system-ram-size))
                       "MB"))
     ("ecl" ("ecl"))
     ("cmucl" ("cmucl"))))
```

Save it. And restart emacs. Then the correct indentation at least will work.

There are more settings which are convenient. (E.g. automatically showing you the expected function arguments while you are writing common lisp code etc. - To have them, you could git clone my `.emacs.d` folder by

```
git clone https://github.com/gwangjinkim/.emacs.d.git
```

And replace your `.emacs.d` temporarily by it. And start emacs. But at your own risk.